# How to resolve - Argument of type is not assignable to type - TYPESCRIPT

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function, that takes among other things an object of functions:

```
type ForMembers<S> = {
 [Key: string]: (arg: S) => void;
};

export default function transform<S extends { [index: string]: any }, D extends { [index: string]: any }>(
  source: S,
  interfaceName: string,
  forMembers?: ForMembers<S>
): D {
  const newObj = extract(source, getKeys(interfaceName));
  if (forMembers) {
    Object.keys(forMembers).forEach((key) => forMembers[key](newObj));
  }
  return newObj as unknown as D;
}
```

The idea is that i can pass any object of functions that i want, but typescript for some reason requires  that i pass all the properties that exist on type , otherwise it throws an error

For instance if D is

```
interface Destination {
name: string;
bio: string;
names: string[];
profession: {
  field: string;
  level: string;
  };
```

And i call the function as:

```
transform<Source, Destination>(sourceData, "Destination", {
  name: () => {},
  bio: () => {},
  profession: () => {},
});
}
```

It will throw an error:

> Argument of type '{ name: () => void; bio: () => void; profession: () => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ForMembers<Destination, Source>'.
> Property 'names' is missing in type '{ name: () => void; bio: () => void; profession: () => void; }' but required in type 'ForMembers<Destination, Source>'.

If i add the missing property - 'names', the error goes away, however i want to pass only the properties i need, not all of them. So the question is this - How to make the function to take as forMembers any combination of properties of D, not necessarily all of them?

Comment: what is `Source` or `sourceData`? Why does the error say `ForMembers<Destination, Source>` when you wrote `ForMembers<S>` in the code snippet? Can you provide a minimum reproducable example?

Comment: Hi, the names of the interfaces are Destination and Source, i think thats the reason

Comment: can you provide `Source` and `sourceData` and double check that your code matches the code in the question?

Comment: My code does not match to the error because i was creating npm package and completely forgot that  i have to use npm link every time, to actually apply changes. Yes, i'm that stupid))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell TS that all properties of an object are optional, using [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype):

```
forMembers?: Partial<ForMembers<S>>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried partial, but got the exact same error.

Comment: Hm, maybe swap Partial and ForMember

Comment: Actually the Partial and 100 of other solutions worked. I was creating npm package forgot that after every change i should use npm link, to actually apply changes))